# Xubuntu and Xubuntu-desktop

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-environments

Is Ubuntu+Xubuntu-desktop exactly the same as installing Xubuntu from the ISO?

If not, what are the differences?

Comment: Ubuntu+Xubuntu-desktop means system will have unity desktop and xfce. Xubuntu ISO means system will have only xfce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu normally comes with what is provided by [`ubuntu-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-desktop) meta-package, whilst Xubuntu normally comes with what is provided by the [`xubuntu-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-desktop) meta-package.

- Xubuntu has the XFCE desktop, but does not have the Unity desktop, whilst Ubuntu + Xubuntu-desktop would have both.
- Ubuntu + Xubuntu-desktop will use more disk space, due to extra packages for Unity etc
- The Xubuntu-desktop package should install all the packages that Xubuntu would come installed with - from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages):

  > ### Ubuntu System Metapackages
  >
  > ...
  >       **xubuntu-desktop:** The XFCE desktop environment, and all the software distributed with Xubuntu

Comment: In my experience, `ubuntu-desktop`  and `xubuntu-desktop` play nicely together (contrary to `ubuntu-desktop` and `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, which will interact often badly --- overlay scrollbar and global menu create strange things...).